# Copy div after drag jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to copy my div inside another div after dragging and allows user to drag/drop the copy again.
Here is my code :

```
<div class="elements">
  <div class="drag">1
  </div>
  <div class="drag">2
  </div>
  <div class="drag">3
  </div>
  <div class="drag">4
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.drag').draggable();

$( ".container" ).droppable({
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.drag').last().after('<div class="drag">'+ui.draggable[0].innerHTML+'</div>') 
      }
    });
```

a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1w34vck6/3/). The problem is : the div's copy isn't draggable.
Thanks

Comment: what is the problem you are facing. What is the expected behaviour

Comment: the div's copy isn't draggable actually

Comment: I'd like to copy the div dropped in `container`, list it after the last `drag` div, allow user to drag/drop this copy again. And when an already dropped div is moved, there is no copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make you copies generated to be draggable again by adding `$('.drag').draggable();` inside the function generating these copies as well.

```
$(function(){

$('.drag').draggable();

$( ".container" ).droppable({
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $('.drag').last().after('<div class="drag ui-draggable">'+ui.draggable[0].innerHTML+'</div>') 
        $('.drag').draggable();
      }
    });

})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1w34vck6/9/)**

**UPDATE**

Adding another class dropped and disbaling drag on it using `$('.dropped').draggable('disable');` will solve the problem I guess

```
$(function(){

$('.drag').draggable();

$( ".container" ).droppable({
      classes: {
        "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
      },
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
      $(ui.draggable).addClass('dropped');
      $('dropped').removeClass('ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-droppable drag');
      $('.dropped').draggable('disable');
        $('.drag').last().after('<div class="drag ui-draggable">'+ui.draggable[0].innerHTML+'</div>') 
        $('.drag').draggable();
      }
    });

})
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1w34vck6/10/)**

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense! And when an "already" dropped div is moved, this element is copied again. I'd like to disable this behavior too.

Comment: @PSport Edited the code, pls check. Had to work a lot on it

Comment: Happy to help! :) One advice when trying to drag into your container it is moving down and so you divs will be coming out of it. You can solve this by appending the copy beneath the container.